# Adding Get-WMI Data To E-mail Body

Tags: email, powershell-2.0

I've got this script that I found that simply sends the time the script was run in an e-mail to the recipient.

```
function send-email
{

$time = get-date 

$EmailFrom = “from”
$EmailTo = “To”
$Subject = “ADX Has Been Deployed”
$Body = “Script has been used on: ” + $time
$SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“e-mail address”, “password”);
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
}


send-email
```

This works a treat, however when I try and add some data into the body of the e-mail using the below code (hostname, IP Address, etc), the data is returned as a complete string.

```
$a = @()
$systeminfo = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | select *
foreach ($item in $systeminfo)
{
$a = $item
}
```

Basically, what I'm after is for the data to be presented in the e-mail one line at a time.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = @()
$systeminfo = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | select *
foreach ($item in $systeminfo)
{
   $a += $item
}
$body = [string]::Join("`n", $a)
```